# See the values inside a object literal in chrome devtools .

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I was just playing around with jBox.js , espically the tooltip functionality of this particular plugin and basically as soon as you click on the tooltip the following code is executed:

```
this.pointer = {
  // "position" is "bottom" in this scenario.
  position: (this.options.pointTo != 'target') ? this.options.pointTo : this._getOpp(this.outside),
  // "xy" is "y" in this scenario.
  xy: (this.options.pointTo != 'target') ? this._getXY(this.options.pointTo) : this._getXY(this.outside),
    align: 'center',
    offset: 0
};
```

(ofcourse alot more lines of code are executed , but i am interested in the lines of code.)

If you check the `source` in chrome and open the jBox.js file the above snippet is on the 575th line, **[LINK HERE](http://purplefront.net/tooltip/tooltip.html)**.

Now if you check the object literal, when the script gets executed , is it possible to see in the `source` tab in chrome the actual values of `position` and `xy` ? Well that would be my one and only question.

I know this is possible with function, I.E. if you have a function, you can set a breakpoint and as soon as that line of code gets executed you will see in the source what are the values of the parameter's . can the same be acheived with the snippet of code i posted above too ?

It would be of immense help if this can be answered, because i am debugging a script that is above 500 lines of code and console.logging stuff is getting quite tedious.

Thank you.

Alex-z.